# NodeMCU and Flow Sensor Battery Issue

Tags: iot, arduino-esp8266, nodemcu

I have an issue about my flow sensor connected to my NodeMCU ESP2866. I want to make it powered wirelessly and therefore I need a battery. The problem is however, the sensor requires 5V+ but my NodeMCU is only able to handle 3.3V.

Is it possible to power them from different batteries? If so, how? Is there a better way to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

NodeMCU has a Vin pin that is connected to a voltage regulator (usually LD33). This regulator supports up to 15V as input (it also has a terrible dropout voltage).

If you are supplying NodeMCU with >5V, then you can just use this pin and wire directly to the sensor.

If you are supplying NodeMCU with 3V3, then you will need to use a step up converter. [This thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350892/step-up-3-3v-to-5v) might help. Also, if you are using a battery rated exactly 3V3, be aware that its voltage will drop and that NodeMCU starts behaving strangely around 2.7V (although its datasheet specifies from 2.5-3.3V).

You can also use 2 different batteries, make sure their are both grounded.